How to efficient remove OData from XAF API and replace standard .NET 6 Web API Controllers?
I just wan't to have OData and EDM model in my project, because I don't need it. But scaffolding created it. Every try to remove .AddOData extension gets some error and you have to dig so far, that in the end you wakeup without whole XAF in your project.
So, can I resign from OData API and create Custom/Standard ASP.NET Core Web API instead?
